# Rails 3: CanCan stuck on a redirect loop!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, infinite-loop, cancan

I'm upgrading my rails 2.3.8 app to Rails 3.

I'm using cancan for authorization which seems to be working for most of my actions apart from the root.

The way I have cancan is setup is that when a user is not authorized, he is redirected to the root url of the app (and displayed a short message).

You don't need to be logged in to view the root action yet cancan keeps trying to redirect to it - so it's stuck on a redirection loop.

This all worked in rails 2.3.8 so it makes me suspect one of two things:

1. The new version of cancan works differently
2. I've made a mistake in setting up routes

This is the root action / controller in routes.rb:

```
root :to => 'tours#browse_tours'
```

And this is what I've specified in cancan's ability.rb model (for non-logged in users):

```
can :browse_tours, Tour
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please post more details about your ability.rb file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the upgrade from an earlier version of CanCan something changed.

I discovered the problem was actually in my controller. In my controller I had:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :tour, :through => :user
```

I could use the above and 'browse_tours' was still accessible for guest users.

To work around this I told cancan not to bother performing authorization on the action:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :tour, :through => :user, :except => :browse_tours
```

It does and doesn't make sense. In ability.rb we create an instance of User (without any roles) if the person has not logged in (just as in http://asciicasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

E.G.

```
user ||= User.new
if user.has_role? :admin
 #allow admin to do stuff
elsif user.has_role? :normal
 #allow signed in user to do stuff
else
 #guest user so allow to read
 can [:read, :browse_tours], Tour
end
```

This 'role-less' user was then allowed to do certain things but for some reason this doesn't fly in the new version of CanCan.

Anyway, hope this explanation helps someone else out.